# How to enable signing (for redistribution) for all dependent dlls built via vcpkg?

Tags: c++, grpc, digital-signature, software-distribution, vcpkg

In one of my C++ projects, i wanted to use [grpc](https://chromium.googlesource.com/external/github.com/grpc/grpc/+/HEAD/src/cpp/README.md#install-using-vcpkg-package). When i use this, 8 dependent binaries get built and copied over to the output folder. 3 of these, abseil_dll.dll, re2.dll, cares.dll do not have Product Name, Version & Copyright information when checked in file properties.

[Propety Page for re2.dll file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yg4UZ.png)

How can i ensure all the dlls are built with their necessary information? Also, the signing process is not clear. Do we have the ability to get these dlls signed by the creators? or should a user sign these dlls (generated through vcpkg) before redistribution?

Am looking for process followed by other organisations to redistribute packages created through vcpkg.

Comment: If upstream does not provide such information (i.e. does not have .rc file with it) then you're out of luck. Either create a ticket in upstream bug tracker or patch the library yourself. Signing is usually done by you when you create a redistributable package.